# How to use return statement properly

Tags: python

I want the terminal to return to the loop until the answer is 'OK'

Tried adding return to make the statement return into the lopp until the answer is desired

```
while true:
   agreement = str(input("Answer only in Yes or No OK? \n write 'OK' if you agree \n"))
   if agreement == str("OK"):
      print("Thanks")
   else:
      print("You can't move ahead without writing 'OK'")
       return agreement

itworking = str(input("Are you living?\n"))

if itworking == str ("yes"):
   print("You are living dude!")
else:
   print("You are dead hehe")
```

Comment: `true` needs to be `True`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Why is your `return` part of the `else` condition? Why are you asking for `"OK"` and testing vs. `"yes"`? Maybe you need `break`.

Comment: you can only use `return` inside a function.

Comment: @tadman It's not; it's not part of *anything*, as the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `return` (which is about returning a value from a function) with `break` which you can use to leave a loop?

Comment: @chepner I was going to gripe about the indentation, but figured someone else would point that out first.

Comment: What's the point of asking if the user agrees?

Comment: The prompt says to answer with `Yes` or `No`, but then it checks if they enter `OK`. That's confusing.

Comment: Also, remove all `str`s - they are useless in this code fragment.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response for how to loop until valid input